# Java: ArrayList print

Tags: java

I have a ArrayList and in that ArrayList are Objects of class CD and DVD (subclasses of Artigo). What I need is to show all CD's in the ArrayList.
Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Artigo> artigos = new ArrayList<Artigo>();

    for(CD i: artigos)                          
    {                                                   
        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print("\n--------------------\n");
    }
}
```

What's wrong and how can i fix it?
Appreciate any help.

Comment: Where you add CD to artigos list?

Comment: You must tell us, what's wrong! Then we can tell you, how to fix it. So what do you expect to happen, and what happens actually?

Comment: If `CD` is a subtype of `Artigo` then each element of `Artigo` is not necessarily a `CD`. So it doesn't make sense to use `CD` variable to iterate through them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Printable objects**

Override `Object.toString` in your `Artigo` objects.

This will allow the elements of your `List` to be printed "human-readable", instead of using the `Class@hashcode` idiom of `java.lang.Object`.

**Inheritance**

You are using fast-enumeration to iterate over child classes of your parametrized type for your `List`, which won't compile because of a type mismatch.

You should instead use:

```
for(Artigo a: artigos) {
    ...
}
```

If you only want to print `CD` elements, add a condition within your loop:

```
if (a instanceof CD) {
   ...
}
```